# Flash Builder break on warning (of a binding error)?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I've injected some silly binding error in a large legacy project and am having trouble finding it.
This is the error output to the console:

> warning: unable to bind to property 'length' on class 'String' (class
>   is not an IEventDispatcher)

I've tried stepping through with the debugger try to track down where this is happening but there are many thousands of lines of code and with event messaging, a very non-linear program execution.

**Question:** Is there any way to make Flash Builder break on a warning like this? If not, is there some other method, trick or hack for tracking this down?

Comment: Show us code. Try to clean project Or restart flash builder if no any error previously.

Comment: the warning is not relevant why do you need to remove it?

Comment: Warnings are not errors, having warnings in a project is not that big of a deal and in most cases have no impacts on the project itself. If this was causing any trouble whatsoever you would know where the trouble occur and where to look for but since you don't I'm guessing you only want to get rid of it because it bothers you to see it in the output panel, am I right?

Comment: If that's the case then describe what bug occurs in your project due to this warning and why you cannot locate the bug. FYI there are many AS3 operations that are perfectly legal and will cause warnings like binary assignment conditional and others. Something's telling me I am right and you just want a clean output panel ...

Comment: Here add "show-binding-warnings=false" in compiler options. Warnings are not errors and they do not imply that there's anything wrong with the code at compile time and at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by (wait for it...) trying to bind to a property that isn't marked as [Bindable].  In this case, you have a string variable whose length property is being used for data binding.

This is most likely caused by adding "myvar.length" as a property in the MXML tag for a component -- something like

`<s:TextInput maxChars="{myInputString.length}" ...>`

Flex will create the data binding for you automatically, but it doesn't realize at runtime that the property isn't Bindable - meaning, if there are changes to the property value the notification won't propagate to update the listeners.

Data binding uses mx.binding.PropertyWatcher to do the binding, and PropertyWatcher.updateParent is where the warning is output.

Comment: The cause is known and is not rocket science, he wants to know how to find it easily among a bunch of files.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I suggest a breakpoint in PropertyWatcher.updateParent - that includes the object that is being complained about...